# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$vuelidateErrorExtractor') in quasar framework

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, vuelidate

I want to create a simple web app using the quasar framework. to validate form inputs, I'm planning to use vuelidate and vuelidate-Error-Extractor. so I have installed these packages and created a boot file using quasar CLI "vuelidate-error-extractor". and also and add that filename into the plugin in quasar config

but there is a problem when initializing vuelidate-Error-Extractor. can someone help me to fix this

this is the error which i got when try to config this

[image: console errros]

**this is the boot file**

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import VuelidateErrorExtractor, { templates } from "vuelidate-error-extractor";

const messages = {
  required: '{attribute} is required.',
  requiredCustom: '{attribute} is required.',
  min: "Field {attribute} should be exceeded 5 characters",
  onlynumbers: '{attribute} should be numbers.',
  maxLength: '{attribute} should be less than {max} characters.',
};





// "async" is optional;
// more info on params: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files
export default boot( ({app,Vue}/* { app, router, ... } */) => {
  // something to do
  app.use(Vuelidate)
  app.use(VuelidateErrorExtractor, {
    messages,
    attributes: {
      name: "Name",
      email: "Email",
      text: "Text"
    }
  });

  app.component("formWrapper", templates.FormWrapper);
})
```

**quasar config**

```
/*
 * This file runs in a Node context (it's NOT transpiled by Babel), so use only
 * the ES6 features that are supported by your Node version. https://node.green/
 */

// Configuration for your app
// https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js

const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers');

module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/supporting-ts
    supportTS: false,

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/prefetch-feature
    // preFetch: true,

    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files
    boot: [
      'i18n',
      'axios',
      'vuelidate'
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-css
    css: [
      'app.css'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v5',
      // 'fontawesome-v5',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons', // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'

      // transpile: false,
      // publicPath: '/',

      // Add dependencies for transpiling with Babel (Array of string/regex)
      // (from node_modules, which are by default not transpiled).
      // Applies only if "transpile" is set to true.
      // transpileDependencies: [],

      // rtl: true, // https://quasar.dev/options/rtl-support
      // preloadChunks: true,
      // showProgress: false,
      // gzip: true,
      // analyze: true,

      // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
      // extractCSS: false,

      // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/handling-webpack
      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      chainWebpack (/* chain */) {
        //
      },
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
    devServer: {
      server: {
        type: 'http'
      },
      port: 8080,
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-framework
    framework: {
      config: {},

      // iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      // lang: 'en-US', // Quasar language pack

      // For special cases outside of where the auto-import strategy can have an impact
      // (like functional components as one of the examples),
      // you can manually specify Quasar components/directives to be available everywhere:
      //
      // components: [],
      // directives: [],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: []
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      pwa: false,

      // manualStoreHydration: true,
      // manualPostHydrationTrigger: true,

      prodPort: 3000, // The default port that the production server should use
                      // (gets superseded if process.env.PORT is specified at runtime)

      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        // Tell browser when a file from the server should expire from cache (in ms)

      chainWebpackWebserver (/* chain */) {
        //
      },

      middlewares: [
        ctx.prod ? 'compression' : '',
        'render' // keep this as last one
      ]
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest'
      workboxOptions: {}, // only for GenerateSW

      // for the custom service worker ONLY (/src-pwa/custom-service-worker.[js|ts])
      // if using workbox in InjectManifest mode
      chainWebpackCustomSW (/* chain */) {
        //
      },

      manifest: {
        name: `wedeliver`,
        short_name: `wedeliver`,
        description: `A Quasar Framework app`,
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#027be3',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-128x128.png',
            sizes: '128x128',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {
        // https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#options

        // OS X / Mac App Store
        // appBundleId: '',
        // appCategoryType: '',
        // osxSign: '',
        // protocol: 'myapp://path',

        // Windows only
        // win32metadata: { ... }
      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'wedelivershopapp'
      },

      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      chainWebpackMain (/* chain */) {
        // do something with the Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // extendWebpackMain also available besides this chainWebpackMain
      },

      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      chainWebpackPreload (/* chain */) {
        // do something with the Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // extendWebpackPreload also available besides this chainWebpackPreload
      },
    }
  }
});
```

**package.JSON file**

```
{
  "name": "wedelivershopapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Quasar Framework app",
  "productName": "wedeliver",
  "author": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.0.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
    "vuelidate-error-extractor": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.22.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just getting this same error while trying to get Hello.js working with Quasar.  In my case it was happening because I had code that was trying to set a property on `app.prototype`, but with Quasar boot code you need to set the property on `app.config.globalProperties` instead. ([Here's an example in Quasar's documentation section on Boot files](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#axios))

So I had to change:

`app.prototype.$hello = hello`

to:

`app.config.globalProperties.$hello = hello`

So my guess is that in your case there's some similar line in the Vuelidate code that needs to be changed.